# agrupar tuplas de una lista

Tags: python, python-2.7, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy interesado en agrupar tuplas de dos elementos de una lista de tuplas que compartan algún elemento. ¿Cómo podría hacer ésto en python?

Por ejemplo, si tengo la lista `[(1,2),(2,5),(3,4),(4,1),(8,2)]` la respuesta debería ser `[[(1,2),(2,5),(8,2)],[(3,4),(4,1)],[(1,2),(4,1)]]`

Uno de los requisitos es que la solución fuera eficiente pues la lista original de tuplas es bastante grande.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer también [ask]. En su estado actual me temo que la pregunta será cerrada por la comunidad, pues es básicamente la solicitud de escribir un programa y el objetivo del sitio es el de resolver dudas específicas de programación. Es decir, si nos muestras lo que has hecho ya y explicas cual es tu dificultad o error específico, seguramente encontrarás ayuda. Un saludo.ç

Comment: ¿Y por qué no habría de aparecer en el resultado el grupo `[(1,2), (4,1)]` , ues también tienen un elemento en común, el 1? Creo que el problema no está del todo bien definido

Comment: Tienes razón @abulafia, debería aparecer. He editado la pregunta con tu aportación. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho las siguientes hipótesis:

1. La lista podría tener tuplas repetidas. En los grupos del resultado en cambio no queremos repeticiones.
2. La tupla `(x,y)` es diferente de la tupla `(y,x)`.
3. El orden en que se listan los grupos en el resultado final, o las tuplas dentro de cada grupo, es irrelevante.

Con estas condiciones, el siguiente código crea un diccionario cuyas claves son números que han sido observados en alguna tupla (por ejemplo, 1, 2, 3, etc.) y cuyos valores son conjuntos con las tuplas que contienen ese número.

Creo que la forma más sencilla de entenderlo es con el ejemplo.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lista = [(1,2),(2,5),(3,4),(4,1),(8,2)]

grupos = defaultdict(set)
for tupla in lista:
  for v in tupla:
    grupos[v].add(tupla)
```

Resultado (variable `grupos`):

```
defaultdict(set,
            {1: {(1, 2), (4, 1)},
             2: {(1, 2), (2, 5), (8, 2)},
             3: {(3, 4)},
             4: {(3, 4), (4, 1)},
             5: {(2, 5)},
             8: {(8, 2)}})
```

Que se lee en la forma siguiente:

- Tuplas en que aparece el 1, => `(1, 2), (4, 1)`
- Tuplas en que aparece el 2, => `(1, 2), (2, 5), (8, 2)`
- Tuplas en que aparece el 3, => `(3, 4)`
- etc.

Ahora podemos quedarnos solo con los casos en los que el conjunto tenga más de un elemento, y formar así la lista con el resultado que buscabas mediante la siguiente  *list comprehension*:

```
[ list(tuplas) for n, tuplas in grupos.items() if len(tuplas)> 1]
```

```
[[(1, 2), (4, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 5), (8, 2)], [(4, 1), (3, 4)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo creo que te ayudará.

```
list = [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 1), (8, 2)]
L = []
B = []

for i in range(len(list)):
    #print(list[i])
    if 2 in list[i]:
        L.append(list[i])
        print(">>>"+str(L))
    else:
        B.append(list[i])
        print(">>>"+str(B))

print(str(L)+","+str(B))
```

Resultado:

```
[[(1,2),(2,5),(8,2)],[(3,4),(4,1)]]
```

PD: He puesto el número 2 estático (para hacer las comprobaciones) ya que veo que comentas que quieres juntar una lista de tuplas que compartan algún elemento, sin embargo el (4,1) también comparte elemento con (1,2).

Saludos!

Comment: Parece que estás separando la lista en dos grupos: uno con las tuplas que contienen el 2 y otro con las que _no contienen el 2_. Esto no coincide con lo preguntado por el usuario, salvo para este ejemplo particular. Además ya no es válida tras la última edición de la pregunta.